# How do I extract the underlined value in red below and save it as a list?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

How do I extract the underlined value in red below and save it as a list?

You want to extract the Memcode value in href to a in p tag using soup.

However, I don't know how to extract it at all.

Please help me.

[image]

My code

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
url = "https://www.council.ulsan.kr/kor/councillor/viewByPerson.do"
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
sourcecode = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sourcecode, "html.parser")
      
    
list = []
for href in soup.find("div", class_="memList memList-col-3").find_all("a"):
    print(href)
```

Comment: The question as it stands now is incomprehensible - did an edit go wrong?

Comment: @Mister Mak 

Hello, thank you for your answer.
I've solved the problem completely.
However, the question disappeared because the editing function was pressed incorrectly.
Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split on the "=" and take the -1 index. I also changed the class .

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
url = "https://www.council.ulsan.kr/kor/councillor/viewByPerson.do"
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
sourcecode = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sourcecode, "html.parser")
ids = [i['href'].split('=')[-1] for i in soup.select('.btn-home')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the problem easily.
You guys are geniuses. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this, using [`css selector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471325/4985099)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get('https://www.gjcouncil.go.kr/kr/member/name.do')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("div[id='member_list'] > ul > li > a"):
    print(a['href'].split("/")[2])
```

---

```
08070
00716
08040
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
url = "https://www.council.ulsan.kr/kor/councillor/viewByPerson.do"
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
sourcecode = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sourcecode, "html.parser")

href_list = []

for href in soup.find("div", class_="memList memList-col-3").find_all("a"):
    if href['href'] == '#LINK':
        pass
    else:
        href_list.append(href['href'][-7:])
        
print(href_list)
['7620212', '7670126', '7670420', '7650601', '7890930', '7800407', '7660925', '7641102', '7731222', '7801011', '7570803', '7770106', '7590808', '7700831', '7580115', '7710713', '7680112', '7621125', '7711117', '7680213', '7640925', '7591214']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the problem easily.

You guys are geniuses. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best method is using `Regular-Expression`.

**Check out this code :**

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "https://www.council.ulsan.kr/kor/councillor/viewByPerson.do"
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
sourcecode = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sourcecode, "html.parser")

list_ = []
for href in soup.find("div", class_="memList memList-col-3").find_all("a"):
    list_.append(href['href'])

regobj = re.compile(r'memCode=(\w+)')
final = list(filter('#LINK'.__ne__, list_))
result = list(map(lambda i: regobj.search(i).group(1) ,final))
print(result)
```